# how to convert df.info() into data frame. df.info()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, converters

how to convert `df.info()` into  data_frame.

I want to be able to merge this dataframe with other dataframe.

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 458 entries, 0 to 457
Data columns (total 9 columns):
Name        457 non-null object
Team        457 non-null object
Number      457 non-null float64
Position    457 non-null object
Age         457 non-null float64
Height      457 non-null object
Weight      457 non-null float64
College     373 non-null object
Salary      446 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4), object(5)
memory usage: 32.3+ KB
```

Answer (score 3):

Building off of the previous answer. The solution below will place the string collected from the `buffer` directly into a pandas DataFrame without having to save a temp file to disk

```
import io
buf = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buf)
s = buf.getvalue()
lines = [line.split() for line in s.splitlines()[3:-2]]
pd.DataFrame(lines)
```

Explaination:

- `s.splitlines()` - creates a list from the string where a new line character is found
- indexing `[3:-2]` - removes the first three lines and last two so that it will fit nicely into columns for the data frame

Comment: While this works for the question, but I'd like to highlight that this will only work if there are no spaces in the name of your columns. The `line.split()` splits the line at each space and thus, the columns formed in the dataframe through `lines` are based on these splits.

Answer (score 2):

While the `info()` method directly prints the information to the output, and even when you use the buffer to extract the info, it extracts it in the form of **text lines**, which are hardly useful for further processing.

The above mentioned solution does work, but it creates a problem when your column names have spaces or are inconsistently named for you to be able to use the `line.split()` with some other separator character.

I couldn't search of any way to do this using the default `info()` method. So, I made my own function to do this. And it is not that complicated.

```
def infoOut(data,details=False):
    dfInfo = data.columns.to_frame(name='Column')
    dfInfo['Non-Null Count'] = data.notna().sum()
    dfInfo['Dtype'] = data.dtypes
    dfInfo.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    if details:
        rangeIndex = (dfInfo['Non-Null Count'].min(),dfInfo['Non-Null Count'].min())
        totalColumns = dfInfo['Column'].count()
        dtypesCount = dfInfo['Dtype'].value_counts()
        totalMemory = dfInfo.memory_usage().sum()
        return dfInfo, rangeIndex, totalColumns, dtypesCount, totalMemory
    else:
        return dfInfo
```

Usage:

```
variable = infoOut(yourDataFrameObject)
#or
var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 = infoOut(yourDataFrameObject,details=True)
```

This function will return the exact table structure as returned by the `info` method for your supplied dataframe, and that too in a dataframe format. Further, if you supply with an argument `details=True`, then it will also give our other information that `info()` gives out like memory, summary counts, etc.

Modify the function as you like.

Good day.

Comment: You can modify the function to return specific item instead of returning them all together like I have shown.

Comment: Great work on the function @Meet

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a text file :

```
import io
buffer = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)
i = buffer.getvalue()
with open("df_info.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(i)
```